# C# using an object data source for my reporting solution

Tags: c#, telerik-reporting

Suppose I have a class like this

```
public class Product
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Category {get; set;}
    public int ID {get; set;}
}
```

And I also have a class like this

```
[DataObject]
public class Products
{
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return new List<Product>
        {
            new Product() {Name = "Product1", Category="category1", ID=1 },
            new Product() {Name = "Product2", Category="category2", ID=2 },
            new Product() {Name = "Product3", Category="category3", ID=3 },
            new Product() {Name = "Product4", Category="category4", ID=4 },
        };
    }
}
```

If I have 10 instances of the Product class, how would I add the information contained within those instances to my list?

Example:

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return new List<Product>
        {
            new Product() {Name = "Instance1_Name", Category="Instance1_Category", ID=Instance1_ID },
            new Product() {Name = "Instance2_Name", Category="Instance2_Category", ID=Instance2_ID },
            new Product() {Name = "Instance3_Name", Category="Instance3_Category", ID=Instance3_ID },
            new Product() {Name = "Instance4_Name", Category="Instance4_Category", ID=Instance4_ID },
        };
    }
```

This is for a reporting solution I am trying to use from Telerik which uses an object data source to generate content on the report.

Comment: "How do I go about removing the hardcoded values in the List and adding some dynamic values retrieved at runtime? " Where will the data come from? Database? Text file? Web form? What format is it in?  These are questions that need to be addressed to solve your specific problem.

Comment: As mentioned in the title and example, the data comes from an object.  It would be in the form of the product class in this case (which contains string and integer types).

Comment: I get that the objects are the data source for the report, but objects don't magically have data - you are creating them with hard-coded values.  Where should the NON hard-coded values come from?  I'm not suggesting you hook the report up to a different data source.

Comment: The data from the object comes from a database.

Comment: So your question is "how to I populate a list of objects with data from a database" and is not specific to Telerik reporting.  There are many ways to do that - I'd suggest expanding your search scope to find examples.

Comment: No, not sure how you arrived at that conclusion.  The objects I am working with have the data I require from the database.  My question is how to get the data contained in those objects to my report.

Comment: The question in your post is "How do I go about removing the hardcoded values in the List and adding some dynamic values retrieved at runtime? "  That's how I arrived at that conclusion.  If that is NOT your question then please edit it.

Comment: Yes, the dynamic data I am referring to comes from my objects.  I have updated the question.  Hopefully it is a little more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help from people from this post I was able to arrive at the solution:  [C# how can I preserve data between class instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768149/c-sharp-how-can-i-preserve-data-between-class-instances)

Here is what the final code example looks like:

```
 public class Product
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Category {get; set;}
    public int ID {get; set;}

    public static List<Product> ProductList =
        new List<Product>();

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GenerateReport()
    {
        return ProductList;
    }

}
```

The key was to combine my two previously distinct classes and make the List a static member to preserve the data.