# C# how can I preserve data between class instances?

Tags: c#, instance-variables

Apologies for the vague title, but I am not really sure how else to explain it.

Given Class A, B and C.

If Class A contains a List, how can I preserve the data in that list so that Class B and C can access the data in the list (even if B and C both new up their own instance of Class A)?

Classes B and C must create their own instances (this is out of my control).

I am using this class as my object data source, and let's say I cannot modify the contents of Class C.

Following is an example class:

```
[DataObject]
public class Product
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Category {get; set;}
    public int ID {get; set;}

    public List<Product> ProductList =
        new List<Product>();

    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GenerateReport()
    {
        return ProductList;
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe a parent gives them all a copy to the same "data". More detail would be helpful in understanding what you're trying to do here. `static` may be the right answer, in some cases.

Comment: You can inherit B and C from A, or define a property in B and C of type A

Comment: Use Class `Static` variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use static as defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static

Then you will be able to access the class properties instead of instance properties.

Comment: Yes, but I need my class to be an instance type, to continually make changes and add more than one instance of the class to the list.  Also, I don't think a List can use a static type?

Comment: Awesome, I think you may be right about making my List<T> static.  However I am now having other issues, I will get back to you once I get things sorted out,

Comment: Well, that worked!  I can't believe how much time I spent trying get that sorted out. Thanks!  I just made my List<T> static.

Comment: By the way... I think I am taking your pluralsight course "Object-Oriented Programming Fundaments in C#" which I think is excellent so far!

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple options to implement this. As said in other answer you can use Static property/field in Class A for accessing list.

Second option is to use Dependency injection. Create constructors of class B and class C so that they must be initialized by passing in instance of A.
e.g.

```
class A
{
  public List<object> AList {get;set;}
}

class B
{
  private A localInstance;
  public B(A instance)
  {
    localInstance = instance;
  }

  public void SomeMethod()
  {
     // access to list from instance of A
     var a = localInstance.AList
  }
}

// Similar implementation for class c
```

Comment: You're rather making a dependency here to class `A`. True you're not creating the class yourself but still.

Comment: You should also consider an Update() method, in case the list changes

Comment: @Deadzone Even if one uses static field to access Class A data it would still be dependency. It's will be hooked directly into the Class B which is not a good design.