# C# How to preserve data between class instances

Tags: c#, list, static, instance-variables

So I had previously asked this question and thought I got an answer, unfortunately the answer does not behave as I need it to so I am asking again with further explanation of the behavour I am trying to get.

Here is a link to my previous question: [C# how can I preserve data between class instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44768149/c-sharp-how-can-i-preserve-data-between-class-instances)

Here is the problem description:

Given class A

If Class A contains a List, how can I preserve the data in that list so that object B and C (instances of class A) can access the data in the list (even if B and C both new up their own instance of Class A)?

** I should note that this is for a reporting solution I am trying to implement using an object data source.

I thought the following code was the solution to my problem

```
[DataObject]
public class Product
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Category {get; set;}
    public int ID {get; set;}

    // this method let's calling code add an instance of this class to the 
    // to the ProductList
    public void AddItemsToList()
    {
        ProductList.Add(this);
    }

    // static list allows me to preserve the list data
    public static List<Product> ProductList =
        new List<Product>();

    // This method is used to return an IEnumberable object to my reporting 
    // solution (Telerik Reports)
    [DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select)]
    public IEnumerable<Product> GenerateReport()
    {
         return ProductList;
    }

}
```

The problem with the above code is that each time I update the static list with an instance, it will overwrite the data from the previous call to List.Add().  So if I add 5 instances of this product class (each with different property values set) my list will contain 5 items all with the most recently set property values.

What I need:  I need my list to not only preserve my data (somehow) but to ensure my list contains copies of each instance (not just 5 copies of the last instance added to the list).

I can provide more details if necessary and test code if required. Any ideas would be very helpful.

Comment: If you *actually* added 5 different items, you'd have 5 different items.   If your list has 5 copies of the same item, then it's because you added 5 copies of the same item.  That said, the whole thing seems like a really bad idea.  You shouldn't have a static list like this.  Whatever code needs a list of some of these items should have the list, and add items as appropriate.

Comment: Right... that makes sense.  Just because I am calling the  AddItemToList a bunch of times does not mean I am adding a new instance of my class to the list(duh) I am just adding the same instance with updated properties.  I will make my calling code send in a new instance and see if that works.

Comment: If your question involves a class `A`, `B`, and `C`, why does your code example show none of that? Frankly, the question is not clear at all. I doubt a singleton will help here. But, you need to explain better what you've tried and why that didn't work. Explain why classes `B` and `C` have their own instances of `A`, but for some reason need access to a list object owned by some _other_ instance of `A`. All you're going to get are dead-end answers, until you can be more specific and present your question in a clearer, more understandable way.

Comment: You're right.  I think I am really only dealing with class A here and multiple objects of class A,  I think what I should say is B and C or objects of Class A.  But since objects are instances of class A they get their own copy, I needed some what for object B and C to have access to the same underlying data, hence the static method coming into play.  I will update my question to reflect more accurately what the problem is.  Right now though it looks like Servy has got me on the right track as my list now contains distinct copies.

Comment: @Servy you definitely got me on the right track.  My list now contains distinct copies (I was adding 5 copies of the same instance).  So now things are working as I expect them but my report is now having some issues.  I will probably create a new question for that though.  Also, I agree this is probably not the way I should be doing it... I'll see if I can read through the reporting API I am using and find a more suitable method of adding data to my report from an object data source.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you're getting the same property values in every instance because you're adding the **same** instance to the list. The list has 5 entries that all point to the same object.

To fix this, you could clone the current instance of the `ProductList` (or create a new instance with the correct property values) and add that to the list instead of adding the actual current instance. That way each entry in the list will point to a different object and updating the current object will not affect them.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is exactly what was wrong.  It seems to be working now.  Now I have other issues to contend with as this all relates to a reporting solution I am trying to implement that uses an object data source.

Comment: Since I cannot mark Servy's comment as the answer I will mark this as the answer becuase it is indeed the problem and the solution.  I added new instances of the class with the correct properties for that instance to my list.

Answer (score 0):

you should use singleton pattern, so the you will have only one instance of class A, and it will be accessed from anywhere in your application. so the data in class A will be shared and can be accessed from class B and C and any other classes.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never implemented the singleton pattern before, hopefully it is not to hard to learn because it sounds like now would be a good time to learn.  I will look into it. Thanks.

Comment: it is very easy, you will mark your constructor as private and you will create a property to get the already defined instance of your class.
you can check this link 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're after the Singleton Pattern.
John Skeet has a nice [article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) about the various implementations of Singleton in C#. You can pick one that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look.